# Whole list getting re-rendered while using context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a context called PlayingContext, whose provider is wrapped inside the App.jsx file. I am using this context in MainSound.jsx and MainSoundList.jsx. The context changes state when a list is clicked. However, the problem is that every list inside the MainSoundList gets changed regardless of the specific list I clicked on. I'm certain that this is because of the context, because when I set the state locally inside MainSound.jsx, the problem doesn't happen. I could use the useState hook locally in MainSound but then if I navigate to a different route and come back again, the state gets lost. I need to store the state as well, which is why I used context, but that doesn't seem to work. How to fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

MainSound.jsx -->

```
import React, { useContext, useRef, useState } from 'react';

import classes from './MainSound.module.scss';
import svg from '../../../../assets/svg/sprite.svg';

import PlayingContext from '../../../../context/playing-context';

const MainSound = ({ imageSource, title, audioSource, onClick }) => {
  // const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const { isPlaying, setIsPlaying } = useContext(PlayingContext);

  // const audio = React.useRef(new Audio(audioSource));

  const playClickHandler = () => {
    onClick();
  };

  return (
    <li className={classes['main__sound']}>
      <div
        className={`
        ${classes.box} ${isPlaying ? classes.isPlaying : ''}
      `}>
        <img className={classes['box__img']} src={imageSource} alt={title} />

        <button onClick={playClickHandler} className={classes.box__playicon}>
          <svg>
            <use xlinkHref={`${svg}#icon-${isPlaying ? 'pause' : 'play'}`}></use>
          </svg>
        </button>

        <button className={classes.box__hearticon}>
          <svg>
            <use xlinkHref={`${svg}#icon-heart`}></use>
          </svg>
        </button>

        <div className={`${classes.box__menu} ${isPlaying ? '' : classes.hidden}`}>
          <div className={classes.box__icons}>
            <svg className={classes['icon__volume']}>
              <use xlinkHref={`${svg}#icon-volume-2`}></use>
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className={classes['main__text']}>
        <h3 className={classes['main__title']}>{title}</h3>
        <p className={classes['main__author']}>by Valdemaras</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};

export default MainSound;
```

MainSoundList.jsx -->

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';

import MainSound from './MainSound';
import MainSoundSkeleton from './MainSoundSkeleton';

import classes from './MainSoundList.module.scss';

import { storage } from '../../../../config/firebase-config';
import { db } from '../../../../config/firebase-config';
import { getDocs, collection } from 'firebase/firestore';

import PlayingContext from '../../../../context/playing-context';

const MainSoundList = () => {
  const [sounds, setSounds] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const { isPlaying, setIsPlaying } = useContext(PlayingContext);

  console.log('is mounted');

  useEffect(() => {
    const getSounds = async () => {
      try {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const data = await getDocs(collection(db, 'sounds'));
        const sounds = data.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
        setSounds(sounds);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    getSounds();
  }, []);

  const soundsList = sounds.map((sound) => (
    <MainSound
      key={Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)}
      // title={sound.title}
      // imageSource={sound.imageSource}
      // audioSource={sound.audioSource}
      onClick={() => {
        setIsPlaying(!isPlaying);
      }}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <>
          <MainSoundSkeleton />
        </>
      ) : (
        <ul className={classes['main__sounds']}>{soundsList}</ul>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default MainSoundList;
```

I have tried using redux as well, same happens.

Answer (score 0):

first, I'm not sure that I understand the problem correctly. you have a list of MainSound components and each one of them can be playing? if so, the context can't just return a boolean. how do you know which MainSound is playing? it seems to me that setIsPlaying should receive both an id and a value.

But, even after you fix that, and isPlaying is a map, if you expose that map on the context value, all the list items will re-render. [docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext#caveats)

React looks at the context value as a single value, and each time anything in it changes all the components using the context are re-rendered.

you can solve it by storing who is playing in the `MainSoundList` and passing `isPlaying` to each `MainSound` in props + wrapping each `MainSound` component in [`React.memo`](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo) (otherwise all of them will re-render when their parent, `MainSoundList` is re-rendered). But memoization has its price..
the list will re-render each time because its state has changed.

Or you can build a small external store that will be storing who is playing and expose an API that never changes - this way there is no memoization and only the `MainSound` component that started playing will re-render.
You can create this store in a context provider or in the list.

[here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/serene-neco-1uoj8n) is a sandbox with the second solution.

** with redux it should have worked, so if you show what you tried to do maybe I can help

** also I guess that only one sound should play at a time..